# how to compare document from 3 different collections

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I have three collections named employees, leaves, events in my mongodb database. I want to fetch employees who are not on vacation nor have an event scheduled on a specific date.

**employees Model**

```js
    const employeeSchema = new mongoose.Schema({  
    name: { type: String, required: true },  
    role: {  
    type: String,  
    required: true,  
    },  
    image: { type: String, required: false },  
    phoneNumber: {  
    type: Number,  
    required: true,  
    },  
    email: {  
    type: String,  
    default: null,  
    required: \[true, "Email is required"\],  
    },  
    empType: {  
    type: String,  
    required: true,
    },  
    password: { type: String, required: true },  
    lastLogin: { type: Date, default: null },  
    token: { type: String, default: null },  
    deviceId: { type: Array, default: null },  
    });
```

**Events model**

```js
    const eventsSchema = new mongoose.Schema({  
    venue: { type: String, required: true },  
    eventType: { type: String, required: true },  
    eventDate: { type: Date, required: true },  
    startTime: { type: Date, required: true },  
    departureTime: { type: Date, required: true },  
    numberOfCameras: { type: Number, required: true },  
    numberOfDays: { type: Number, required: true },  
    packagePrice: { type: Number, required: true },  
    teamLead: { type: String, required: true },  
    teamList: { type: Array, required: true },  
    teamMembers: [],  
    });
```

**leaves model**

```js
    userId: { type: mongoose.ObjectId, required: true },
    startDate: { type: Date, required: true }, 
    endDate: { type: Date, required: true }, 
    reason: { type: String, required: true },     
    leaveSeekerName: { type: String, required: true },    
    leaveSeekerRole: { type: String, required: true },    
    status: { type: String, default: "pending" },     
    },  
    {       
    timestamps: true,   
    }
```

so i am  want to get employee who are not on leave nor assigned an event on specified date

Comment: You can use `$lookup` twice

Comment: Can you add an example documents with the expected output to the question?

Answer (score 0):

The question is not completed.
First, you should complete the linked relationship among the 3 tables.

If your 3 schemas use `_id` in `employees` and `teamMember` of `events`, `userId` in `leaves` to tag someone as the same person on the below.

```js
const employeeSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    name: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    role: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
    },
    image: {
        type: String,
        required: false
    },
    phoneNumber: {
        type: Number,
        required: true,
    },
    email: {
        type: String,
        default: null,
        required:true,
    },
    empType: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
    },
    password: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    lastLogin: {
        type: Date,
        default: null
    },
    token: {
        type: String,
        default: null
    },
    deviceId: {
        type: Array,
        default: null
    },
});

const eventsSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    venue: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    eventType: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    eventDate: {
        type: Date,
        required: true
    },
    startTime: {
        type: Date,
        required: true
    },
    departureTime: {
        type: Date,
        required: true
    },
    numberOfCameras: {
        type: Number,
        required: true
    },
    numberOfDays: {
        type: Number,
        required: true
    },
    packagePrice: {
        type: Number,
        required: true
    },
    teamLead: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    teamList: {
        type: Array,
        required: true
    },
    teamMembers: [
        {
            _id:mongoose.ObjectId,
            name: String,
        }
    ],
});

const leaveSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    userId: {
        type: mongoose.ObjectId,
        required: true
    },
    startDate: {
        type: Date,
        required: true
    },
    endDate: {
        type: Date,
        required: true
    },
    reason: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    leaveSeekerName: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    leaveSeekerRole: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    status: {
        type: String,
        default: "pending"
    },
}, {
    timestamps: true,
})
```

You can consider use aggregations like this:

```js
db.employees.aggregate( [
    {
        "$lookup": {
            "from": "events",
            "localField": "teamMembers._id",
            "foreignField": "_id",
            "as": "events"
        }
    },
    {
        "$lookup": {
            "from": "leaves",
            "localField": "_id",
            "foreignField": "userId",
            "as": "leaves"
        }
    },
    {
        "$match": {
            "$and": [
                {
                    "events.startTime": {
                        "$lte": nowTime
                    },
                    "events.departureTime": {
                        "$gte": nowTime
                    },
                    "leves.startDate": {
                        "$lte": nowDate
                    },
                    "leaves.endDate": {
                        "$gte": nowDate
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    }
] )
```

You may need to adjust the value of `nowTime` and `nowDate`.